# is it possible to block the installation of android app in rooted device?

Tags: android, linux, flutter, android-studio

is it possible to block the installation of the android app on a rooted device?I want to block the installation of the android app on the root device. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't whether it can be done or not but what you can do is make your app unusable on rooted device, means user can not use it even if it is installed.

for that all you have to do is  determine if your app is running on rooted device or not from any of method below,(code for android)

```
public class RootUtil {
    public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
        return checkRootMethod1() || checkRootMethod2() || checkRootMethod3();
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
        String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
                "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su", "/su/bin/su"};
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su" });
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            if (in.readLine() != null) return true;
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (process != null) process.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

and then if `device is rooted` then `navigate` to a " with message like "app can't be run on rooted device" with `exit button`.

**For Flutter**

you can use [trust_fall](https://pub.dev/packages/trust_fall) package from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/),

```
import 'package:trust_fall/trust_fall.dart';
bool isJailBroken = await TrustFall.isJailBroken;
```